# Use output from one python file as input in another

Tags: python-3.x, file-io, arguments, return-value

I have a python program that has folders that contain scripts that have individual roles in manipulating data. I want to be able to specify from a 'main' file in the root directory the inputs of the these scripts using the output from the last script that was run.

eg. python3 script2.py -i inputFile

Where inputFile is described by a file that was written to by the previous script. Say, script1.py.

The main script looks something like this:

```
os.system("python3 subdir1/script1.py -c subdir1/config.json")
os.system("python3 subdir2/script2.py -c subdir2/config.json -i inputFile")
```

I'm using wsl with ubuntu 16.04.

But I can't figure out how to return filename to the main script in the root directory. All I can get is the error code that was returned by the script upon exit.

Comment: The real question here is, which operating system? Also, please provide code, otherwise we cannot really help you.

Comment: There is tons of ways to accomplish what you are trying to do, but it depends on what exactly you want to do. Two python subscripts with one python script that runs them? Or one bash script on top of them? Er maybe even .bat script on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution/workaround. I used the scripts to create a JSON file that stores the filename. I then read that in the next script